# Why does iCloud take up 30+ gigs of storage on my Mac?

Tags: icloud, macos, storage

For some reason iCloud is taking up over 30 gigabytes of storage on my MacBook Air. How do I get rid of this? I though the whole point of iCloud was to save space not eat it up! I'm on macOS Sierra 10.2

[image]

Comment: iCloud is for syncing content across devices.  As it 'learns' which docs you use and how often, it will offload those docs to the cloud until you need them (if you have it set for this in Preferences).  If you want permanent cloud storage, you should use a different service, like Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your iCloud Drive contents are cached. After looking over the [new storage management features in Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht206996), doesn't look like the "Optimize Storage" feature will clear that.

If you go to About this Mac > Storage > Manage > iCloud Drive are there options there to remove files locally? I don't use it personally so mine's empty.  :)

Comment: There is no option as far as I can see :(

Comment: Drat.. Well, you can click Optimize and clear up some space (the "lined" part to the far right in your screenshot above). As fsb mentioned, I believe the system will automatically clear up some space from your cached iCloud Drive when needed.

Comment: Ya thats fine, I'm just disturbed that iCould could be taking up storage that's unnecessary. I have plenty of room left on iCloud Drive, so I have no idea why it would be keeping a "cash" of 30+ gigs on my computer!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove iCloud storage from your Mac by going to System Preferences → iCloud, then uncheck the checkbox next to iCloud Drive.

Beware that everything will be removed from your Mac but remain in iCloud only. This means that anything added to your Mac after this will not be stored in iCloud and you'll have to do it manually on the web.

[image: Uncheck the box to remove iCloud]
[image: Remove iCloud from Mac]