# 202 GB in "com.apple.bird"

Tags: macos, icloud

I've read that com.apple.bird, is a part of icloud on Mac but mine is 202GB!! is taking a lot of my iMac space.  Can anyone help me?
Some say it is not safe to delete this cache, but I need to find a way to clean this one up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To find out exactly what is taking up the space, follow these steps:

1. Go to Finder
2. Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key while you click on the Go menu
3. Select Library
4. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now
5. Within the Library folder open the Caches folder
6. Now you'll see a com.apple.bird folder

Now you can browse within this folder to determine what's taking up the space.

If you happen to have WhatsApp installed and it's taking up a lot of the space, then refer to [my answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281266/whatsapp-using-huge-space-on-my-mac-ssd)

Comment: I wonder if we need to find the main thread for this for a canonical answer. - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268112/why-does-icloud-take-up-30-gigs-of-storage-on-my-mac

Comment: Agreed. I'm sure I've answered a couple of similar questions to this one. The only thing is I wonder whether it's actually three canonical answers we need: 1. *What is com.apple.bird?*, 2. *How can I see what's taking up space in com.apple.bird?*, and 3. *How can I free up space in com.apple.bird?* (Is that too many, or can we combine 2 or more?)

Comment: Perhaps [Tetsujin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220008/168832) is the canonical answer to the first one? It's not clear to me whether the answer to the 3rd one is the same regardless of the data, but if so perhaps my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281269/168832) is a possible candidate?

Comment: How does this help cleaning anything? The original poster already knows the folder and what size, and only doesn't know what c an be deleted safely or otherwise the directory being shrinked, this only helps to look at the folder, which already happened...